# how to map a drive with powershell

Tags: powershell

How on PowerShell do I map a network drive with user name & password?

I am trying to do an equivalent of command prompt (cmd.exe) command:

```
net use G: \\10.10.10.1\f$ /USER:prod\joe myStrongPasswordHere
```

I found on this site solution below, but I get an error below. Here is command and error:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network$net.MapNetworkDrive
("r:", "\\10.10.10.1\$f", $false, "prod\joe", "myStrongPasswordHere")
```

> `New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object
>   []'.
>   At line:1 char:18
>   + $net = new-object <<<<  -ComObject WScript.Network$net.MapNetworkDrive ("r:", "\\10.10
>   .10.1\$f", $false, "prod\joe", "myStrongPasswordHere")
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingExcept 
>      ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands 
>      .NewObjectCommand`

Thanks

Comment: You might have better luck on serverfault

Answer (score 5):

Honestly I would just use `net use` e.g.:

```
PS> net use G: \\10.10.10.1\f$ /USER:prod\joe myStrongPasswordHere
```